# How to have search functionality on association models as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

By using a railscast video i create a simple search that works on same model. But now i have a model that shows associated model data as well and i would like to search on them as well.

Right now i managed to make it semi work, but i assume i have conflict if i add the field "name" into the joins as i have two models that have a column named "name"

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      key = "'%#{search}%'"
      columns = %w{ city station venue area country plate_number }
      joins(:services).joins(:washer).joins(:location).where(columns.map {|c| "#{c} ILIKE #{key}" }.join(' OR '))
    else
      where(nil)
    end
  end
```

What do i need to change to be sure i can search across all columns?

Comment: I think when you have ambiguous field name after join then you can mention table_name.field_name so it remove the ambiguity and works. what you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you have ambiguous field name after join then you can mention table_name.field_name so it remove the ambiguity and works. something like.

```
joins(:services).joins(:washer).where("services.name = ? or washer.name = ?", "test", "test")
```